# Delayed_job not sending Rails 3 emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

Note: Using Rails 3.1 and current delayed_job gem.

I have a `User` model that calls `after_create :mail_confirmation`.

The `mail_confirmation` method looks like the following, per the delayed_job instructions:

```
def mail_confirmation
    UserMailer.delay.registration_confirmation(self)
end
```

The `UserMailer` is:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "test@mysite.com"

  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "#{user.full_name} <#{user.email}>", :subject => "Test registration email")
  end
end
```

The job is queued, and the output from `rake jobs:work` makes it seem as if it completed successfully:

```
[Worker(host:mymac.local pid:73694)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:mymac.local pid:73694)] Class#registration_confirmation completed after 1.3659
[Worker(host:mymac.local pid:73694)] 1 jobs processed at 0.7288 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

There is no error but the email is never sent. It works fine if I remove `delayed` from the method call in the `User` model and go with the standard `deliver` method:

```
def mail_confirmation
    UserMailer.registration_confirmation(self).deliver
end
```

How can I find out what is happening when the job is processed? Any idea how to fix it?

---

**Update** It appears that it is related to this:

[NoMethodError with delayed_job (collectiveidea gem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602203/nomethoderror-with-delayed-job-collectiveidea-gem)

Comment: When is the last time you restarted your `rake jobs:work` task?  It requires restart every time you change code so it might not have your latest mailer code in it.

Comment: I restart it every time I change the code and want to try it out.

Comment: Whether your tlsmail gem installed and configured ?

Comment: That's not the issue because it works fine with the delay. I tried it on a deployment to Heroku and get the following error `Class#registration_confirmation failed with NoMethodError: undefined method 'registration_confirmation' for Class:Class - 2 failed attempts` What does that mean? Is delayed_job not seeing the Mailer class?

Comment: It appears this might have something to do with Heroku running a beta version of Bundler 1.1

Comment: Looks like this is the issue: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah i had this same issue. @Clay is correct, there is an issue at the moment: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/323

I resolved this problem by reverting back to the previous version of delayed_job.

```
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issues here. I discovered that for some reason the delay method called on Mailer classes is being handled by the method `Delayed::MessageSending#delay` instead of `Delayed::DelayMail#delay` which instantiates the right performable (which is `PerformableMailer` instead of `PerformableMethod`). It doesn't crash the job because `PerformableMethod` just calls the method without the deliver.

Take a look at:

- delayted_job/lib/delayed/message_sending.rb
- delayted_job/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb