# NoMethodError with delayed_job (collectiveidea gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

**UPDATE: There's been a patch for this issue: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/023444424166ba2ce011bfe2d47954e79edf6798**

**UPDATE 2: For anyone running into this issue on Heroku specifically, I've found downgrading to Rake 0.8.7 and using Delayed Job version 2.1.4 works, while delayed job v3 does not (though with the patch it does work on local). This is on the Bamboo-mri-1.9.2 stack.**

I am trying to implement delayed_job on a rails 3.1.0 app locally. I ran the migration and 
installed the gem files:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Following the documentation on the collectiveidea github (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). I am making the delay call from my controller as follows:

```
EventMailer.delay.event_message_email(current_user, @event_message)
```

This causes the task to be added to the job table but when I run rake jobs:work it logs the following error:

```
Class#event_message_email failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `event_message_email' for Class:Class - 6 failed attempts
```

I've looked at the the other delayed_job NoMethod error questions on SO but none address this specific error or provide a solution to it. The collectiveidea page mentions that this format without the deliver method call is a hack for how Rails 3 mailers are setup, so I'm wondering if perhaps this documentation may be some how outdated, and if there is a new way to call mailer methods?

Update: also calling the mailer method without delay works fine, and I am running it on the default rails server so the issue with Thin mentioned in the collectiveidea faq does not apply. Thanks

Comment: When is the last time you restarted your `rake jobs:work` task?  It needs restarting after every code change.

Comment: Does EventMailer.event_message_email(current_user, @event_message).delay.deliver work?

Comment: @iWasRobbed: yes, I've tried that

Comment: @Unixmonkey No that doesn't work, in fact it gives a helpful error saying that the delay should be placed before the method call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this problem by switching to delayed_job (DJ) version 2.1.2.

I am using:
rvm
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) 
rails 3.0.9

Gemfile:
gem "delayed_job", '2.1.2'

Before this I tried to use the latest version of delayed_job:
gem "delayed_job", :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git'
for me it was v3.0.0.pre

But:
   rails generate delayed_job
didn't generate migrations file. I created it manually. Then after 'rake db:migrate' I've got the table for storing delayed_job queue. And then, when I was thinking that all must be worked correctly, I've got the same error.

When I tried to find the source of this error, in 'delayed_jobs' table I have found that delayed_job's tasks are incorrectly saved. Here is snippet from field 'handler' in 'delayed_jobs' table:

```
--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer 
object: !ruby/class Notifier
```

As I know, delayed_job gets all tasks through Struct class, so the task should be saved with '!ruby/struct' header isntead of '!ruby/object'
Here is the snippet of correctly saved task:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMailer 
object: !ruby/class Notifier
```

To check this I stopped delaed_job process in console. Then I called some method to put DJ's task to DB:

```
Notifier.delay.some_email(current_user, @event_message)
```

Then I manually replaced '!ruby/object' by '!ruby/struct' in 'handler' field.
Then I started DJ 'rake jobs:work', it said me that mail was succesfully sent.

But:
- this task wasn't be deleted from DJ's table
- and mail doesn't get to the recipient

So I've decided that it is a bug in new version of delayed_job. I switched to DJ '2.1.2' and it's worked for me fine.

P.S.: Sorry for my English :)

Comment: hi, thanks for the detailed assessment, upvoted. I made the change to the table field and it also cleared the job so it appears you are correct. I opened this as an issue on the github and will add this as a reference. I haven't yet tried downgrading to 2.1.2, as I am trying a couple other things as well, and I am concerned that this will not resolve the issues associated with rails 3 mailers.

Comment: By the way the issue is at https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/323 if you'd like to follow it

Comment: Sukhoviy , hi, trying to go your route but finding that bundler isn't allowing the install of delayed_job_active_record with a  version of delayed_job prior to 3.0.0.pre. Attempting to use delayed_job 2.1.2 without delayed_job_active_record doesn't seem to work either. Were you able to get a workaround to this? Or should I just drop it and use resque :)?

Comment: Sukhoviy, whoops never mind 2.1.2 works fine without delayed_job_active_record, just forgot to update the gem file

Answer (score 7):

Using Mailer.delay.send_method seems buggy in Rails 3 (they mention it's a hack in the docs). I had the same NoMethodError and solved it by using the alternative method for creating jobs shown in the docs i.e. creating a new Job class with a perform method e.g.

```
class UserMailerJob < Struct.new(:text, :email)
  def perform
    UserMailer.your_mailer_method(text, email).deliver
  end
end
```

Then to create the job, in my controller:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue UserMailerJob.new(@text, @email)
```

It's slightly longer to do this than using delay but it seems to create the jobs correctly and process them reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note. I had this issue and it was because I was passing a variable from the model into the deliver method BEFORE_SAVE. Switching to AFTER_CREATE fixed the issue for me.